# How to solve Ajax.BeginForm calling twice using asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ajax.beginform

My Question:

1. I have a main page some fields when user click save button using Ajax.BeginForm i'm saving the details this is working successsfuly.
2. Inside main form there is one button(task) when user click that button partial window will open then they will fill some details. when partial window save button clicking automatically main page save action method is calling...first it save partial save details then immediately its saving main page details also then i'm getting two time saved successfully message.
3. when main page save button click only it should save main page fields. when partial page save button click it should save partial page fields only(partial page save i'm using jquery.

Main Page:

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("savePhase", "Search", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ChmHeaderPage",OnSuccess= "OnSuccessMain" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChangeRequestList.FirstOrDefault().changeId);
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChangeRequestList.FirstOrDefault().Phase);

            <div class="col-md-offset-0 panel-body">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Importance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ImportanceVal, new SelectList(Model.Importance, "OptionId", "OptionName", Model.ImportanceVal), new { @class = "form-control", @Title = "Message Need to be Show" })
                    </div>

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Urgency, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UrgencyVal, new SelectList(Model.Urgency, "OptionId", "OptionName", Model.UrgencyVal), new { @class = "form-control", @Title = "Message Need to be Show" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                    @Html.Label("Enter Task*")
                    <button type="button" id="Analysisbtn" class="btn btn-link " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Select Task</button>



                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-open strech-modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Analysis</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    @Html.Partial("_TaskPage")
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Form actions -->
                    <div class="row panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" name="buttonValue" class="btn btn-danger" value="Close">Save & Close</button>

                            <button type="submit" name="buttonValue" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">Save</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
        }
```

Partial Page:

```
        @model www.ChangeManagementTool.ViewModels.SearchViewModel
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-
       multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                 Task
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="table-responsive center-block" data-tab-content="@item.Key" style="display:@displayText">
                        <table class="table table-responsive sena" id=@item.Key>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Department</th>
                                <th>Plant</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <th>Responsibles</th>
                                <th>DueDate</th>                                  
                            </tr>

                            <tbody>

                                @foreach (var analysisTask in item.Value)
                                {

                                    <tr> 
                                        <td>
                                          --DisplayFor code
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          --DisplayFor code
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          --DisplayFor code
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          --DisplayFor code
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            --DisplayFor code
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                }
                                </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>

                }
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" id="btnSaveReal" class="btn btn-primary ">Save Task </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery Save Coding

```
                  <script type="text/javascript"> 
                      $('#btnSaveReal').click(function (e) {

    var listex = [];
    debugger;
    $('#RealTask tbody tr').each(function (index, ele) {
        var saveItem2 = {
            ChangeId: $('#ChangeIdR').val(),
            PlantId: $('#PlantIdR' + index).val(),
            DepartmentId: $('#DepartmentIdR' + index).val(),
            MstTaskId: $('#MstTaskIdR' + index).val(),
            AffectedItemId: $('#AffectedItemIdR' + index).is(":checked")
        }
        listex.push(saveItem2);
    })

    //Save Coding
    var url = applicationRoot + '/Search/SaveRealizationTaskdetails';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'objmodelRel': listex, actionR: 'AnalyzeRealize' }),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (Data) {
            if (Data.status) {
                alert(Data.responseText);
            } else {
                alert(Data.responseText);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});

function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-heading')
    .find(".more-less")
    .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
}
$('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

Controller Code:

```
    public ActionResult savePhase(SearchViewModel objmodel, string buttonValue)
    {
    save code---------------
     return RedirectToAction("FetchChgReqDetails");
    }

     public JsonResult SaveRealizationTaskdetails(List<ChangeRequestRealizationTask> objmodelRel, string actionR)
    {
       --save code      
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = true, responseText = "Successfuly saved!" }, JsonRequestBehavior= JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Comment: change Partial view button type="button"  insted of  type="submit"  and then check

and on main save send all detail in ajax including Partial view data

Comment: wow! joshi. thank you so much. simple mistake. i have changed type=button. its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your questions i will suggest you to try below this if it helpful to you.

First change Partial view button type="button" instead of type="submit"

and on main form submit send all data including Partial view data using AJAX